# How to run spring boot application on cpanel or cyberpanel?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, cpanel, cyber-panel

How can I run Kotlin Spring Boot application on Cyberpanel or Cpanel?

Hello, I develop some API projects on Kotlin Spring Boot. At the same time, I use postgreSQL. So, I need postgreSQL in cpanel or cyberpanel. As much as I know, cyberpanel does not support postgreSQL.

Anyway, How can I run spring boot application on cpanel? Is it difficult or should I directly run it on linux server without webpanel?

Actually I would like to solve this problem. There are no any documentation to run spring boot applications on webpanels.

Answer (score 0):

There are no documentation on this because it is not the purpose of those panels to provide this functionality.
I do not know Cyberpanel but, in cPanel, by default, there is no Java installed. There is a possibility to provide Tomcat 8.5 from WHM but I have never tried (and do not plan to).
Also cPanel comes with MySQL or MariaDB - no Postgres there either.

So no, you cannot do what you want. Furthermore I do not understand why you would wish to do so?

If you have access to the OS and want to run a Spring Boot app, why would you like to install cPanel as well? Both are quite heavy to run under and you might get some weird issues after auto-updates.

On the other hand, if you are looking for a way to run Spring Boot from some sort of web hotel, I don't think I will be possible without asking your provider (and they will probably say no).

Comment: Actually, I have my own VDS. I run all websites om cpanel. Maybe this is no such a good idea to run Java Application on cpanel. However, the another problem, if I run it directly via OS, there is security problem. At least web panels supplies security a bit.

Comment: If you have your own VDS with cPanel installed, you can try to build your Spring Boot applications as war file and install Tomcat on cPanel (it is an option in EasyApache). But I would guess that you won't be able to use latest Spring as Tomcat in cPanel is a bit old.